# jQuery .html() doesn't work in IE8

Tags: php, jquery, html, web

I have an AJAX response that returns information using `$_GET` and is then set as the `HTML` of a container. This works in Chrome, Safari, FireFox, Opera, but not IE8.

```
$(function() {
  $('#content .entry-content a.mais-menos').click(
    function(){
      $('#content .entry-content a.mais-menos').css('background-position','bottom left');
      if($(this).siblings('.descricao-campanha').css('display')=='block'){
        $(this).css('background-position','bottom left');
        $(this).siblings('.descricao-campanha').slideUp(1000);

      }else{
        $('#content .entry-content .descricao-campanha').slideUp(1000);
        $(this).css('background-position','top left');
        $(this).siblings('.descricao-campanha').slideDown(1000);

        var mae = $(this).siblings('.descricao-campanha');
        var codigo = $(this).siblings('.cdPost').attr('value');

        if (mae.children('.carregando').is(":visible")){
          $.get('<?= get_bloginfo("url") ?>/get_associado.php', {cd:codigo}, function(retorno) {
            // mae.children('.carregando').hide();
            mae.html(retorno);
            // alert(retorno);
          });
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
  );
});
```

If I alert `retorno` I can see that the data has been returned, but when I append it to the `div`, it fails in IE8.

Can someone please help me understand why this fails and how to resolve it?

Check the error in this page http://www.superredems.com.br/associados/

This is what Retorno return, in case of no image.

```
<div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="descricao-mercado">
    Fone: 67 3245 3330<br />
    Praça Das Nações, 330
    Bairro Centro
    <a target='_blank' href='http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anast%C3%A1cio_%28Mato_Grosso_do_Sul%29' title='ANASTACIO - MS'>ANASTACIO - MS</a>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <p></p>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="imagens-destaque-associado">
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does your response text contain new `HTML 5` elements?

Comment: Usually, it fails when your html is faulty. Forgetting to close a tag per example. Can you post your `retorno`?

Comment: retorno is a big code, but i will post it

Comment: Is there an error in the console (F12)?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @SDC I'm using the version 1.6.1, already test the 1.8.3 and continue, and with 1.9.1 dont work nothing.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker dont return no error in console

Comment: looks like there is an extra closing `</div` at the bottom, remove it and try

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes, i remove it now, but continue the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extra div closing tag in the response. Remove it, it will work fine

```
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="descricao-mercado">
    Fone: 67 3239 1810<br />
    Av João Garcia De Souza, 46
    Bairro Jardim Nova Água Clara
    <a target='_blank' href='http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81gua_Clara' title='ÁGUA CLARA - MS'>ÁGUA CLARA - MS</a>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
<p></p>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="imagens-destaque-associado">

<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
</div> **<-- this is extra**

<script>
    $('img').parent('a').colorbox();
</script>
```

Comment: I saw that, but when i remove the problem still was in the program.

Comment: i put the file online now, check it, still the same problem

Comment: @user2144208 it seems to be working fine for me, can you clear the browser cache and try again

Comment: Thanks Man, now works, thanks a lot, how can i recognize you man xD

Answer (score 2):

When appending markup in IE8 you need to ensure that it is valid, this bug has been documented [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12581) and is usually caused by a tag not being closed.

Answer (score 2):

@PeteUh is exactly right. Here is the html you were trying to set when I gave it a try:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="descricao-mercado">
    Fone: 67 3239 1810<br />
    Av João Garcia De Souza, 46
    Bairro Jardim Nova Água Clara
    <a target='_blank' href='http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81gua_Clara' title='ÁGUA CLARA - MS'>ÁGUA CLARA - MS</a>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
<p></p>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="imagens-destaque-associado">
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<script>
     $('img').parent('a').colorbox();
</script>
```

As you can see you have 1 too many closing div tags.

Comment: i put the file online, without the extra </div> but dont work

Comment: Thanks for the mention, I've upvoted because you were right but OP didn't upvote.